# To perform actions or events based on the table view cell scrolling speed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a scenario where if I move table view cells(scroll up/down) based on moving I want to do two operations
(1) want to make a view outside the table view as invisible based on speed it will be fade off and  (If table view cell is moving slowly the view will fade off slowly if it is fast fade off fast).

(2) I have a button out side the table view which has to be moved based on the speed (If table view cell is moving slowly button will move slowly if it is fast button moves fast)

And I'm taking a view controller inside which this table view and another view and button is presented

I have used this methods

```
(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint scrollVelocity = [[self.tableView panGestureRecognizer] velocityInView:self.tableView];
}
```

Now what to do next to do these actions 1 and 2? Can any one please help me!

Is there any way to find out x and y positions instead of velocity ? 
I am thinking that if I get the x and y positions while scrolling I can hide the view considering particular positions ?

Hope you understand my requirement !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get the `x` and `y` positions of the `UITableView` during scrolling. Since a `UITableView` inherits from `UIScrollView` - you have access to those methods as well.

Here is some code that will get `x` and `y` of the `UIScrollView`

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scroll
{
    NSInteger yCords = scroll.contentOffset.y;
    NSInteger xCords = scroll.contentOffset.x;
}
```

And since you already have the velocity - I think you have all you need to achieve your goals.

Comment: No problem, happy coding!